# m-d-Y to d-m-Y PHP 5.2

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

I've got a string in the date format `m-d-Y`, and I need it `d-m-Y`. How can I do that in **PHP 5.2?** 
The most common answer `DateTime::createFromFormat()` here on stackoverflow doesn't work in PHP 5.2, and `new DateTime()` + `$date->format('d-m-Y')` doesn't change the format.

Thanks,
Thew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$parts = explode('-', $dateString);
var_dump($parts[1] . '-' . $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[2]);
```

Comment: Or [do what it says here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2167925/561731)

Comment: Yep. But even though I like `DateTime` - if all what we need is just swap `m` and `d` - then it is overkill

Comment: lol True. Thats why I gave you a `+1` ^_^

Comment: Its the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($yourdatestring));
```

Comment: AFAIK, PHP interprets x-y-z dates as d-m-y and x/y/z dates as m/d/y, so this won't work.

Comment: so is this solution ever applicable to date conversions being that strtotime doesn't know how to differentiate between months and days when they're both <= 12?